# Retrieve Identity Verification Image for Recipient

Tags: c#, docusignapi

Our business has a requirement to retrieve and store an image of the recipient's ID (government issued or passport) after envelope completion. I've been unable to locate any API methods that allow us to do that.

Is there anyway to do this using the C# SDK/API? If you can't do it via the API, what is the easiest way to manually do this?

Comment: are you currently using the DocuSign Identity Verification feature (IDV)?

Comment: @InbarGazit Yes we are.

Comment: ok, we're releasing the API to do what you need in the next couple of weeks. I'll update this thread when it's officially out.

Comment: @InbarGazit Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ID Evidence API](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/idevidence-api/) to do this.

Here is the developer endpont to call:

```
https://proof-d.docusign.net/api/v1.0/events/{entityType}/{entityId}/{eventId}/media/{mediaId}
```

You can also follow the [How to retrieve ID Evidence media](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/idevidence-api/how-to/retrieve-idevidence-media/) articl.e